# Get Last Record of each donor

Tags: mysql, sql, database, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working on a BDS feature for a website in Laravel. Now I've tried asking this question twice here, but somehow I'm not able to ask it correctly, so I'll try to give it 1 last try.

I have 2 tables Donors and DonorRecords. What I want to to is to get all donors and their latest donation date only and only if they have not donated blood in last 3 month. I've tried it by both ways. Eloquent and Query.

Following is my query that I'm using:

```
SELECT  donors.name, donors.mobile, donors.address, donors.blood_group, donors.area, MAX(donor_records.donation_date) AS d_date FROM donor_records JOIN donors ON donors.id = donor_records.id WHERE NOW() > DATE_ADD(donor_records.donation_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

Following are records in my database tables.

Donors:

[image]

DonorsRecord:

[image]

Now, But when I execute the query I only get the record with the donation date "2016-04-12" and not the other one. So can anyone help me with this 1 last time. It doesn't matter if it's from Eloquent or from DB side, both will work fine.

**Update**

Similar to this, I have another query. I have a tables

```
products [id, name, price]
customer [id, name]
purchase [customer_id, product_id, timestamp]
```

How can I get the last product of every customer?

Comment: `donorsRecord` or `donorRecord`?

Comment: use whichever, I'll change it when I'll execute the query.

Comment: `where donorRecord.donationDate > NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MONTH`

Comment: I doubt that there's any question for which the 'accepted' answer is the correct one. But without explaining your problem more clearly, it's a little difficult to be sure. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I'm inserting data simply using Laravel Eloquent.
$donor-save();

Comment: I want to get the people with their last donation date. This is the main thing that I require..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT donors.Name FROM donors JOIN donorsRecord ON donors.id = donorsRecord.id
WHERE NOW() > DATE_ADD(donorRecord.donationDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
group by donors.id;
```

Comment: following error occurs:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
group by id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

Comment: Fixed. It was a space between DATE_ADD and (

Comment: what do you mean sir ?

Comment: Ok, now there's another thing. What if I want to get the latest donation date of the donors which were selected ? When type of query would I write then ?

Comment: add to select max(donorRecord.donationDate)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SELECT DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT donors.Name FROM donors JOIN donorsRecord ON donors.id = donorsRecord.id
WHERE NOW() > DATE_ADD (donorRecord.donationDate, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: If some donors have same name then ?

Comment: Add another field to the query, like date of birth or ID number. It would then show you distinct combinations of name and the other field(s).

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT donors.name FROM donors JOIN donor_records ON donors.id = donor_records.id
WHERE NOW() > DATE_ADD (donor_records.donation_date, INTERVAL 3 MONTH);

Comment: above is my query, now it's giving an error at the end. Is the syntax correct ?

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2